# angular 2: Permission denied to access property "rejection" error

Tags: angular

This question has been asked before but I do not think that my situation quite fits.

I started with the heroes tutorial and have changed the "add hero" code to a form. I do realise that from a controller perspective it would be far better to have this as a separate component and html. And that is fine.

But when I run the current page (form plus a loop of ngFor), the form is displayed but the list of heroes is not. In the browser console I can see the get works and returns the correct records in JSON but then I get

Permission denied to access property "rejection"

Having googled it seems I am accessing something that I do not have permission for such as in a different domain. The set up is that the data access is via a grails app and running angular via ng-serve. The only place (?!?) I could have permission problems is with the data access and that is working.

```
<div>
     <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitAdd()">
     <p>
            <label>Hero name:</label> 
            <input type="text" formControlName="heroName">
     </p>

     <p>
            <label>Hero city:</label> 
            <input type="text" formControlName="heroCity">
     </p>

     <p> Hero Abilities </p>
     <p>
            <label>Flight:</label> 
            <input type="checkbox" formControlName="heroFlight">
     </p>

   <p> 
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button> 
   </p> 
   </form> 

</div>

<ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
            <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}} 
            <button class="delete" (click)="delete(hero); $event.stopPropagation()">x</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So even though the current approach is not the best approach, I would like to know what is causing the error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have seen it mentioned that importing `Observable` fixes it.

Comment: added "import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';" to the component code and no change - same problem. The list of heroes does not appear.

Comment: So I don't know if that helps you at all, but I had the same error message. After a bit of tinkering, I found out that assigning a moment()-object to a variable was causing the problem. Further research revealed that I forgot to add the moment-scripts to my index.html. After I added those it was working fine. Maybe someone else has the same or a similar case and it helps them. And maybe something like that is even your problem?!

Comment: @MerlinK - thanks for this. Can you give a code example as I am not sure what a moment object is.

Comment: @John - Oh of course, sorry. [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is a third party library. In order to use it you create moment-objects i.e. `var date = moment();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the OnInit and that has stopped the error